# Query execution duration is rasing in a linear pattern

Tags: sql-server

We have some projects that are running on a SQL Server and all of them are getting slower as time passes by. I have got a trace file from one of them and I noticed that the duration of our queries are getting higher in a linear pattern

As you can see in the picture :

[image]

What could be the possible causes for such behavior?

As you can see the duration drops to normal after reaching the timeout limit.

Comment: It's impossible to guess from a screenshot that doesn't even contain a query. Post the query, table schemas, execution plan. There may be missing indexes forcing the server to scan all data. Or explicit transactions that force all clients to wait for each other, whether they need to or not. Or both

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that I don't think that this behavior is normal. I am not sure whether it is relevant to our queries or not because we are seeing the same effect on two different projects with completely different architecture.

Comment: You will have to start with a specific query where it is clear that performance degrades, and analyze the execution plan. It is quite likely that it has table scans where proper indexes would be needed to have decent performance.

Comment: Different SPIDs? Some locking/waiting problem - do all these queries end at approximately same time? Then something is holding table lock or lock too many required pages or similar.

Comment: Maybe the `DELETE` query that took `30001 ms` (and may have timed out at that time) was holding locks blocking other queries